# Align first line to the left, while other to the right using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to have the first line of text (or inline-blocks) aligned to the left, while the next one to the right using only CSS? I'm sure it can be done using JS, but am looking for a cleaner and simpler solution.

I have this navigation bar (which is a `<ol>` in the markup). It's usually one-line long, but recently we got a case, when it's grew long enough, so that it broke to the second line. Below is the photo of that. What my boss asked me to do is align the second line to the right, while keeping the first intact.

Now it looks like that:
[image: Broken navigation bar]

What I'm aiming for is this (I'd then make some fixes to make it look prettier than on the picture below):
[image: Navigation bar goal-look]

The markup. All `li` items are **inline-blocks**, but I could change that.

```
<ol class="phase-labels">
  <li class="phase-label phase-current">Company</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">The Policy</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Property Insurance</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Additional Clauses</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Public Liability</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Public Liability Additional</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Employers Liability</li>
  <li class="phase-label phase-inactive">Quotes</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Could you also edit the image to indicate how you actually want it to show?

Comment: I don't think there will be a 'clean' solution as you'd needvery specific breakpoints. JS would undoubtedly be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `direction` propertie + `text-align:justify` to fill up entire `first-line`.

What does this involve? :

1. it reverse the reading `direction` of `li` (as inline-boxes) and
   punctuation.
2. if only one line , `li`s stand towards right.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rlfFE)**

Basic CSS

```
ol {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

Note: too bad `text-align` cannot be overwritten through the pseudo class `:first-line`.

---

You have the `display:flex` propertie too. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyzxG)**

Basic CSS :

```
ol {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

Comment: The idea is very cool, but there seems to be problem with the order in which the elements are rendered. Changing direction to *right-to-left* unfortunately also changes the ordering in the same way. It wouldn't be a problem for me to rearrange them in the markup, for example write them in reverse order, but none of this solutions will work - correct the order - unless you exactly know which elements are part of the first line and which of the second.

Comment: @Robert It is exactly the warnings  i talked about, You have display:flex that could be an option for later browser : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyzxG

Comment: I can't work out any Flexbox solution that would solve that either. The one you presented in the pen is fixed, with all elements sharing 16,63% size. I'm looking for a solution that is dynamic (would work on different lists of variable size and content), where the elements sizes are flexible (depend on the content, not hard-coded).

Comment: @Robert remove width , or set a min-width, but basicly, what you look for doesn't follow the regular flow, you will need somehow to fix this with javascript if no compromise fits you. display:flex and flex-end will react as the text-align thingy test linked earlier anyway. :(. Good luck, regards

Answer (score -1):

I did misunderstand what he was looking for sorry everyone, why not try this. I think the following css should work.

```
ol{
    float: right;
}
ol li{
   float: left;
}
```

This answer is based around the idea that if the nav bar has exceeded the parents width, then it's float won't necessarily matter, but aligning everything to the right ensures it positions where you want. And floating the list items to the left, allows everything to be displayed in the proper order

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: There is even a `::first-line` pseudo selector to select the first line, but it works only with some of the properties and `text-align` isn't one of them. The problem with your solution is I want a dynamic one, that would work if one of the labels change and the line would break in another point.

Comment: `first-line` applies to text, you're trying to align **blocks**, are you not?

Comment: My items are **inline-blocks**.

Comment: I did misunderstand the question, I believe this answer above should help him out though.